# single backslash and split problem in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, escaping, backslash

I have a string like below:

```
let str = '.....\........./..\_';
```

which contains a single backslash, but when i use split('') method it removes the backslash but i need this backslash in the array that returned from split. Please help me to find the solution.

```
console.log(str.split(''));
//result [".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", ".", "/", ".", ".", "_"]
```

Comment: You need `\\ ` instead of `\ ` (i.e. `'.....\\........./..\\_'`), or use ```String.raw`.....\........./..\_` ```. Otherwise the string never contained a backslash in the first place, since you were just needlessly escaping the following character.

Comment: The issue is that the string does not contain backslashes.  Backslash is a special character in strings that escapes other special characters.  You would need two backslashes in the string for it to actually have a backslash in it

Comment: @CherryDT thanks for your comment, it didn't work for because the string is an input so when pass input to the String.raw it also removes single backslashes.

Comment: @Taplar thanks for your comment, but the problem is the string is received from input so  i can not manipulate it because js removes the backslash automatically.

Comment: No, when the string is an input the backslash will stay a backslash. The issue is that when you write it here manually in code, the `\ ` has a special meaning, so the backslash never makes it into the string. Nothing is removed from the string at any point!